# Disabling "Notification Bubbles" in Dev Options is Irreversible

Tags: samsung, notifications, settings, bugs, developer-options

I have a Samsung Galaxy S20FE, running Android 10 and One UI 2.5. After enabling "Notification Bubbles" in the developer settings I decided that it wasn't to my taste and toggled it back off.

However, even though the switch says that the setting is off, apps are still displaying notification bubbles - it seems as though the change was permanent. I have tried a restart, clearing the cache, and deleting the setting as per [this article](https://9to5google.com/2019/04/03/android-q-beta-2-bubbles/). It appears that no matter what I do, the notification bubbles remain.

I am comfortable with using ADB, and would be exceptionally grateful for any help here.